# Retain git operations for AWS Pipeline using ThirdParty GitHub source provider

Tags: github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a pipeline configured to use the ThridParty GitHub source provider as follows:

```
...
Resources:
  DevPipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: my-pipeline
      RoleArn: !Ref 'PipelineRole'
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: GitHub
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Version: 1
                Provider: GitHub
              Configuration:
                Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
                Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
                Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
                OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubToken
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: JavaSource
              RunOrder: 1
...
```

I would like to be able to run `git` operations on the source code in the following build steps. However this source action does not include the `.git` folder in the output artifact.

How can I modify this so that I can access `git` operations on the repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodePipeline recently released new version of the GitHub Source action that does an actual clone of git repository instead of getting the 'zip' bundle from GitHub.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/update-github-action-connections.html

The new GitHub action (version 2) uses the CodeStarSourceConnection. So we just need to specify the CodeStarSourceConnection [1] Source action provider in your pipeline's source stage. The AWS::CodeStarConnections::Connection resource [2] is also supported in CloudFormation. You may reference an existing Connection's ARN, or create a new one in CloudFormation. Existing Connections can be found here [0].

Here is an example template snippet:

```
Resources:
  CodeStarConnection:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeStarConnections::Connection'
    Properties:
      ConnectionName: MyGitHubConnection
      ProviderType: GitHub
  CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              Configuration:
                ConnectionArn: !Ref CodeStarConnection
                BranchName: master
                FullRepositoryId: username/repository
              RunOrder: 1
      ... ...
```

Note: A connection created through CloudFormation is in PENDING status by default. You can make its status AVAILABLE by updating the connection in the console [3]. After the Connection being available, you may use your CodePipeline with the Github version 2 source action.

References:

[0] Connections - https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/settings/connections

[1] CodeStarSourceConnection - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html

[2] AWS::CodeStarConnections::Connection - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codestarconnections-connection.html

[3] Update a pending connection - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/connections-update.html